Save image capture from react-webcam in asset or public folder react js
I’m trying to create a function in react which save image captured from my webcam in the asset or public folder. The path combined with image_name.png will be save in column table. Example ../asset/image.png
The capture work correctly but I want another function to save directly the image in the asset folder
<Form.Group>
                                {/* <Form.Label>Take Picture</Form.Label> */}

                                {picture ? (
                                    <img src={picture} alt="webcam" />
                                ) : (
                                    <Webcam
                                        audio={false}
                                        height={300}
                                        width={300}
                                        ref={imageRef}
                                        screenshotFormat="image/png"
                                        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
                                    />
                                )}

</Form.Group>
